# Problems with jface and RAP

Tags: java, swt, jface, eclipse-rap

I'm developing a view for an application I'm working on, and I'm using jface with RAP. I thought it wouldn't be difficult but I'm not really making any progresses. I have a sketch of what I need to do, but I can't even start the application. Google doesn't help that much :/

Any tip to help me get started?

I tried developing a minimal working example, but it simply doesn't work. Anytime I start the application, I got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context available outside of the
>   request processing.

I'm pretty sure this is a noob error, but I can't fix this! Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The following should be a comment! But I have not enough reps.

There is too little information from you to reproduce the issue but I assume you are mixing up setup options provided by RAP. Read the [*Building Applications*](http://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=application-setup.html&version=2.2) part in the *Developer's Guide* completely. An outstanding well worked out tutorial can be found [here](http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/rap_step0/) which might help you to understand the differences. Try to create your project with all three setup options (1 *RAP with OSGi*, 2 *RAP with Workbench*, 3 *RWT Standalone*).

Just guessing: In the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ) is a quite similar error description which might help. [No context available outside of the request **service lifecycle**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#IllegalStateException%3a_No_context_available_outside_of_the_request_service_lifecycle).